# Como subir archivos PDF a la BBDD con PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

Estoy intentando subir a la BBDD (Que no a una carpeta, sino, a la propia base de datos) documentos tipo PDF, pero estoy teniendo ciertos problemas (sobretodo por obsoletaje de algunas funciones, o por que están hechas para imágenes).

Y me preguntaba si es posible.

Estoy con PHP, y no, no es una opción el subir los PDF al hosting y acceder a ellos solo con la ruta, necesito el archivo dentro de la BBDD.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido, por favor revisa [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) en el centro de ayuda.

Comment: Y si empiezas por mostrar que has hecho? Y cuáles son esas funciones obsoletas de las que hablas

Comment: php 5 o 7??????

Comment: 7.2.14 (según mi wamp jaja)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que escapar la variable donde va el archivo para poder insertarlo:

```
<?php
$con=new mysqli("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$con->set_charset("utf8");
$file = file_get_contents($pathFile);
$file_escap=$con->real_escape_string($file);
$sql="INSERT INTO file (id, file) VALUES ('1','".$file_escap."')";
$resultado=$con->query($sql);
if ($resultado===TRUE) {
    echo "1 record added";
}else{
    die('Error: ' . $con->error);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Hice una prueba con lo tu código, me da este error:

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '%PDF-1.4\n%?쏢\n5 0 obj\n<>\nstream\nx??]?' at line 1

Comment: prueba quitando las comitas simples, ponlo asi: `,".$file_escap.")";`

Comment: No he dicho nada, correcto!!
Esta noche ya entrada, probare con la carga masiva haber como lo hace y si funciona. Cuando lo tenga todo, pondré el método, que creo que es útil y no lo he visto por ningún sitio

Comment: No entiendo. Funciono o no funciono??

Comment: si, es que postee que había un problema y edite para decir "no he dicho nada" (perdón por la confusión generada)

Comment: Bueno te tengo recomendaciones. Si vas a guardar un gran volumen de archivos binarios te recomiendo lo siguiente: Crea toda tu base de datos normalmente y la tabla donde pienses guardar los archivos, guarda los atributos del archivo que necesites, pero no guardes el archivo. Esa tabla debe tener un id entero único autoincremental. Para guardar el archivo crea otra base en el mismo manejador de BD, ponle el mismo nombre y concatenale el año actual al nombre. En esta nueva base crea una tabla con un id entero único que tu vas a poner y va a ser el id de la otra tabla en la otra base.

Comment: Para guardar archivos guarda toda tu infomación en tu base de datos normalizada pero sin guardar el binario. El binario lo guardas en la base que tiene el nombre concatenado y cambiara cada año. Asi que tu aplicación la tienes que programar de esa manera. Para consultas de archivo siempre tendras que saber al menos el año del archivo para saber a que BD ir y obviamente el id. Todo esto es para que los respaldos de producción los puedas hacer en tiempos razonables, y los archivos no tengan tamaños que no se puedan manejar. Yo recibo 40000 PDFs al mes y esta forma es la que me ha funcionado.

Comment: Ademas todo esto lo fui aprendiendo a la mala.

Comment: mmmm mi idea en realidad, es que la tabla tendrá el archivo, un ID, un idUsuario y nombre despedazado  y cuando un usuario entre, se le mostraran directamente los archivos a descargar. Cada Dos años esos archivos se irán borrando. en principio cada año completo me es como 220 megas, así que debería tener espacio de sobra.

Ahora estoy con la parte de ver como hacer para que el usuario se lo pueda descargar jeje (aun no me puse)

Comment: Aquí en México la ley te obliga a guardar esos archivos me parece que 5 años, si es que es documento oficial. Ademas EN UN AMBIENTE PRODUCTIVO con una base de datos bien hecha se supone que UNA BUENA PRACTICA ES JAMAS BORRAR NADA y solo actualizar estatus para dar la sensación al usuario que se borro y esa información queda como histórica. Por ejemplo, que tal si se dan cuenta de un fraude después de 6 años y esa información ya la borraste. Te pondrían como cómplice por borrar las pruebas y terminarías en la cárcel. Por eso mi aplicación es como te explique.

Comment: Ya bueno, en realidad solo pretendemos que tengan un acceso mas fácil a dicha información (la mayoría de los usuarios no tienen ni correo electrónico por lo que no se les puede enviar a través de ese formato), siempre pueden pedir dicha información al gestor. Aun así, si se consigue una BBDD de mas tamaño y lo soporta, no se borrara la info (también es posible que esto evolucione poco a poco)

Answer (score 0):

Buenas por una parte me base en el siguiente tutorial para subir el archivo
http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/tutorial-ejemplo-subir-archivos-bd-guardando-bd-binario-127775/

De dicho enlace, la parte obsoleta es el como conectarse a la BBDD mysql_connect, que ahora se usa  mysql**i**_connect (que es fácil de solventar, pero es cuando me he dado cuenta de lo antigua de la documentacion)
Y la siguiente sentencia de la que no consigo pasar es:

```
$binario_contenido = addslashes(fread(fopen($binario_nombre_temporal, "rb"), filesize($binario_nombre_temporal)));
```

**Error ->** fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in C:\wamp64...php on line 63

fread() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp64...php on line 63

Buscando sobre este error, creo que es por que solo se pueden subir mediante este método estas extensiones ('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'txt', 'gif') por eso preguntaba si sabíais si se puede o no.

Para la parte masiva de la subida estaba basándome en el formulario y bucle de este otro enlace 
https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/codigo/PHP/2580-Subir-uno-o-varios-archivos-al-servidor-y-mover-los-a-una-carpeta.html